# Can't install python pip to docker container

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pip

I'm trying to run a flask app in a docker container. When I try to build a container I get

```
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ['python']
CMD ['app.py']
```

I've tried to use these commands before installing python-pip, but it didn't help:

```
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common 
RUN add-apt-repository universe
```

Comment: usually `pip` is installed directly with newer `Python` and you don't have to install `python-pip` - at least I never had to install `python-pip` on Linux Mint based on Ubuntu. And your error shows that `python-pip` doesn't exists on Ubuntu `apt` servers so maybe it is already installed with Python.

Comment: If you are using ubuntu image and updating the container... there's a very high probability that python and pip are already installed. Maybe it's named as "pip3".

Comment: After `add-apt-repository universe` do `apt-get update -y` again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use package `python3-pip`. Your Dockerfile can look like:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ['python']
CMD ['app.py']
```

**Better option** is to use directly Python image:

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ['python']
CMD ['app.py']
```